# TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'bigint

Tags: javascript

I don't get it why?

```
export const CompanyProfileStub: Company = {
    id: 1
};
```

how do I fix this?

```
export interface Company {
    id: bigint;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this TypeScript? And what's `bigint`?

Comment: because I'm dealing with an Id from postgres that's bigint so it has to be bigint in JS

Comment: Try writing `1n`?

Comment: Then why not assign a bigint literal, as the error message urges you? `id: 1n` or `id: BigInt(1)`

Comment: make it `any` ;)

Comment: I did not infer to call it like that, that's why, which is why I posted this in the first place @VLAZ

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, you can't assign a `Number` to a `BigInt` since it's a different kind of primitive.
You can create a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) in JS using the constructor of the `BigInt` like so:

```
const huge = BigInt(9007199254740991)
```

or using `n` at the end of the number like so:

```
const huge = 1n
```

Comment: thanks much, it wasn't that obvious to me.  `id: BigInt(1)`

Comment: BigInt *is* a primitive in JavaScript.

Comment: @VLAZ according to MDN - `BigInt` is a built-in object

Comment: ok so this answer still stands though right?  Even if it's a built-in object.  TS is a pain in the ass

Comment: @SaarDavidson https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_and_Structure_types https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-bigint-value

Comment: ok, thanks for the correction, I'll change it. the answer still stands though.